# Using git with android source repository retrieved with repo

Tags: android, git, android-source, repository

I downloaded the android source code using repo. But if I try to print git status in that directory where the .repo is present it says

```
 git status
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

What do I have to do to get git working in that directory?

Output of ls -a:

```
cts       external    libnativehelper  prebuilts
abi       dalvik       frameworks  Makefile         .repo
bionic    development  gdk         ndk              sdk
bootable  device       hardware    packages         system
```

Comment: `cd` into the project root and add the output of `ls -a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`repo` is used to easily manage several related `git` repositories. The top level directory (TLD) contains the directory `.repo`. So you can invoke `repo` commands from the TLD.

But there is no `.git` directory at the top level. That tells you that the TLD does not have a git repository. In fact the many git repositories that `repo` manages are all in the various sub-directories. So you'll have to `cd` to a specific sub-directory containing a `.git` folder to issue `git` commands for that repository.

If you wish to perform the same command for all git "projects" managed by `repo`, issue the following `repo` command from the TLD:

[`repo forall -c COMMAND`](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#forall)

Comment: Thats where the .git files are.

Answer (score 1):

You use the  `repo` tool for this repository. The Android source site gives some good information on [version control](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html).

> Repo is a repository management tool that we built on top of Git. Repo
>   unifies the many Git repositories when necessary, does the uploads to
>   our revision control system, and automates parts of the Android
>   development workflow. Repo is not meant to replace Git, only to make
>   it easier to work with Git in the context of Android. The repo command
>   is an executable Python script that you can put anywhere in your path.
>   In working with the Android source files, you will use Repo for
>   across-network operations. For example, with a single Repo command you
>   can download files from multiple repositories into your local working
>   directory.

I'm not sure HOW to make the git commands work in that directory, but from [this link](http://www.innovantesindia.com/wordpress/2011/08/04/repo-reference-why-we-require-repo-on-top-of-git-in-development-project/), and from the definition above I believe repo actually has the power t operform all the git functions. Check the above link for a reference.

> repo status [project-list ]
>
> Show the status of files with respect of current working directory,
>   staging area and most recent commit on the branch (HEAD) in each
>   project specified.

Comment: I used repo start to create a new branch according to the documentation which also states that I can use git along with repo.